# In-app-purchase nib-file?

Tags: ios, nib

A question regarding iOS and in-app-purchase;

Is it possible to load a nib file that has been downloaded  from a server and use it in the application? (e.g. something the user bought trough in-app-purchase?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is technically possible (just as you can load any Nib file you want), but it is disallowed under Apple review guidelines as I understand it. It's not related to in-app purchase, but to loading downloaded code; I believe it is likely this rule applies to nib files.

Of course, as with any borderline topic, it may or may not pass Apple's review, depending on your luck. I wouldn't bet on it, though.